# UIView roundedCorners and UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect produce slightly different results

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer, uibezierpath, cornerradius

I've been looking into re-creating a `UIView`'s `cornerRadius` behavior using a `UIBezierPath`. I have known about the `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` method, and it seemed to me like the cleanest way to achieve the same result.

However, after comparing the results of both methods, there seems to be a slight visual difference between the two, which I don't understand why.

Here are the code snippets and images:
UIView + cornerRadius + backgroundColor:

```
UIView *foo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
foo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
foo.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
[self.view addSubview foo];
```

[image: cornerRadius]

CALayer + bezierPathWithRoundedRect + addSublayer:

```
UIView *foo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
CAShapeLayer *bar = [CAShapeLayer layer];
bar.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) 
                                      cornerRadius:50].CGPath;
bar.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor;
[foo.layer addSublayer:bar];
[self.view addSubview:foo];
```

[image: sublayer]

CALayer + bezierPathWithRoundedRect + mask:

```
UIView *foo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
CAShapeLayer *bar = [CAShapeLayer layer];
bar.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) 
                                      cornerRadius:50].CGPath;
bar.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
foo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
foo.layer.mask = bar;
[self.view addSubview:foo];
```

[image: mask]

While both bezierPath methods (add as sublayer or masking) produced the exact same image, both of them were different than the UIView + cornerRadius method.

Here is the visualized diff:
[image]

What I've tried:

- I tried issuing shouldRasterize, but this only caused a much bigger difference and more blur.
- I tried calculating manually the CGPath by using the correct angles with `CGPathAddArcToPoint` but it produced the same result as using `bezierPathWithRoundedRect`.
- I tried using fillRule as kCAFillRuleEvenOdd.
- I tried setting allowsEdgeAntialiasing to YES.
- I tried creating the circle using UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner, cornerRadii: CGSize) and UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) but still same visual result as bezierPathWithRoundedRect

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For producing these images I was using Xcode 11.5 with an iPhone SE (2nd Generation) on iOS 13.5 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `allowsEdgeAntialiasing`?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1621285-allowsedgeantialiasing?language=objc

Comment: Unfortunately after setting the property, it doesn't change the image visually :( Thanks for sharing!